# Как можно можно вывести определенный столбец в зависимости от локализации проекта на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, php7, laravel-5.7

Это мой первый и тестовый проект на laravel. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно можно вывести определенный атрибут в зависимости от локализации проекта на Laravel.
Например умнея есть в базе данных таблица posts и в нем хранятся новости в двух языках: ['ru_title','en_title',''ru_description','en_description'] и есть глобальная самописная  функция getLocale() которая возвращает "ru_" или "en_".

```
function getLocale($data,$table_name){
$locale=\App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware::getDBLocale();
if ($locale="ru_")
    switch ($table_name) {
        case 'name':
            return $data->ru_name;
        case 'description':
            return $data->ru_description;
        case 'include':
            return $data->ru_include;
        default:
            return null;
    }
else
    switch ($table_name)
    {
        case 'name':
            return $data->en_name;
        case 'description':
            return $data->en_description;
        case 'include':
            return $data->en_include;
        default:
            return null;
    }
```

Пробовал сделать таким образам работает но это я думаю не правильный подход как и структура BD для мультиязычного сайта 
Или есть возможность в самой модели изменить название атрибута например protected $atributes=[getLocale(.'name'=>'name']

Answer (score 1):

Подход примерно правильный, но всегда старайтесь гуглить готовые решения:

https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-translatable

Вот есть еще решения:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088897/multilanguage-database-management-with-laravel

Но как по мне - увеличение таблицы в ширину за счет языков не лучшее решение. Я бы подумал о дополнительной таблице переводов.

Comment: Да, спасибо это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088897/multilanguage-database-management-with-laravel то что я искал,  да в идеале было бы лучше сделать для каждого столбца сделать отдельную таблицу например post_titlies и там ['post_id','locale_id','content'] но я использую готовый админ пакет и там я вообще не смог ее сделать гибким, ну и вот пришлось вот таким обзорам сделать

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно попробовать переписать метод __get у модели

```
class ModelName extends Model
{
    public function __get($key)
    {
        $locale=\App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware::getDBLocale();
        return $this->getAttribute($locale.$key);
    }
***
}
```

И уже потом вызывать $modelName->description

Comment: Да спасибо, но я так пробовал в начале и оно мне изменяла  название id, date и заново приходилось использовать if (in_array('title','description))  я думал может можно сразу изменить похоже нет

Comment: @Iliaz так сделайте проверку на доступность атрибутов перед вызовом getAttribute и я бы присмотрелся к готовым решениям как вам предложил автор другого ответа

Comment: if (in_array($key,['name','description','included','title','excerpt','conditions'])) return $this->getAttribute(getLocale().$key);
        else return $this->getAttribute($key); Да спасибо так и сделал, я пробовал установить готовое решение но я использую готовый админ пакет и они с друг другом вообще не складываются к сожалению